# cropping images from center on the fly - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop

I have a bunch of images, that are various sizes, in terms of width and height.

Some are square, some are rectangle, but I'd like all of them to be width and height of my choice.

I know I can use the width="" and height="" in the

So, what I was looking for, is a possible javascript solution, maybe using jQuery, that will crop the images from center on the fly?

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to save the cropped images or you just want to crop them for viewing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can position the images within a container using CSS. Then ensure overflow: hidden is set on that container.

For example:

```
<style>
.container     { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
.container img { position: absolute; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$image = $('.container img');
width = $image.width();
height = $image.height();

$image.css({
    left: 0 - (width / 2),
    top: 0 - (height / 2)
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
    <img src="example.png" style="width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;left:-10px;top:-10px;" />
</div>
```

Something like that!  By setting the left/top properties of it's position you can simulate a crop.  The above example will take 10px off the top and left of the image.  This example assumes the image is 200px by 200px, obviously edit values for your image.

You may need to reposition the container div so that the image looks like it remains  in the same place.