# HTML Image Don't Resize

Tags: html, css

I have a large number of variable size images that may either be uploaded or found in a database. Without running a script to do the resizing, is there any way to purely modify the HTML or use CSS so that instead of having the image distorted and stretched out to match my allocated dimensions of 300x200, I instead have a 300x200 image cut of out my originally large picture (say for example 400x400)?

My current markup looks like

```
<image data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width:300px; height:200px;" src={{ photo.source_descr }}>
```

Comment: I'm confused, I don't really understand your question... your code should work.

Comment: @DumbSearch but it apparently doesn't, that's the problem `:P`

Comment: @tkbx I think that he doesn't want it distorted and stretched, he wants it cropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to resize the image using CSS/HTML with `height` and `width` without stretching the image. You want to crop it instead.

I'm pretty sure that you're looking for the [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clip) property in CSS. Mix `clip` and `width` and `height` to crop your image so that it isn't stretched, yet cropped to fit the desired `width` and `height`. [Read up more about `clip` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clip)

---

Here is the extra code you requested for your needs (note that it uses jQuery, so you need that embedded for this to work):

```
<style>
.container     { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
.container img { position: absolute; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$image = $('.container img');
width = $image.width();
height = $image.height();

$image.css({
    left: 0 - (width / 2),
    top: 0 - (height / 2)
});
</script>
```

Note that I got the second script from this question: [Cropping images from center on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712950/cropping-images-from-center-on-the-fly-javascript).

Comment: thank you, I believe that this is what I'm looking for. However, my issue is that  I have multiple heights and widths for the images, and it appears that with clip, I need to specify the space away from each of the borders. My HTML is auto-generated, so is there a way to crop not based on the size of the original image but just to crop out the center of the image?

Comment: @user1431282 I edited my answer to suit your request. If this helped, PLEASE mark my answer as correct.